# How to validate an XML using a SCH in java or javascript

Tags: javascript, java, schematron

I have created a tool to create XML files however I now need to validate the generated XML against an SCH (Schematron) file. However, none of the tools I have tried have worked.

As the namespace, URI's can't be accessed.

Is there any tool available that I can use for java or javascript to validate this XML against an SCH file or an XSLT file?

Any answers would be greatly appreciated
Many thanks
~ Ben

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to use the XSLT-based process described on the Schematron web site at http://schematron.com/front-page/the-schematron-skeleton-implementation/ .

The process transforms the Schematron schema into an XSL document, then uses that XSL document to transform the document you are trying to validate. The end result is an SVRL (Schematron Validation Report Language) document that describes any validation issues found.

A shell script process would look like this:

To transform the Schematron schema into XSL:

```
xslt -stylesheet iso_dsdl_include.xsl  theSchema.sch > theSchema1.sch
xslt -stylesheet iso_abstract_expand.xsl  theSchema1.sch > theSchema2.sch
xslt -stylesheet iso_svrl_for_xsltn.xsl  theSchema2.sch > theSchema.xsl
```

To validate an XML document:

```
xslt -stylesheet theSchema.xsl  myDocument.xml > myResult.xml
```

The process could be done in Java using an XSLT library. If your Schematron schema uses XSLT2/Xpath 2, then I would recommend using the Saxon XSLT library.

Comment: Hi Joshua,

I have tried using an approach like this however because the namespace's are from a restricted network it says it is an invalid schema

Comment: Can you provide the error messages that you're getting, and say which step of the process is generating the errors?

Comment: Sorry for the very delayed reply :)

I have resolved issue this by creating a custom validator script that performes the SCH checks